# objectmapper.readValue() fails with error "no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value"

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

My objectmapper.readValue() function throws an error that says "Cannot construct instance of `MyErrorMessage` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value."

What's wrong with my MyErrorMessage class that makes objectmapper fail?

This is the JSON I'm trying to parse.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "id": "43225a4853b5497a",
    "time": "2020-06-03T13:36:03.391814Z"
  },
  "datadetail": {
    "aKey": "hweriu-erw",
    "aTypes": [
      {
        "bKey": "ewrf-7e9f",
        "cKey": "12ddf3",
        "status": "ERROR",
        "errorMessage": {
          "message": "Not found"
        }
      }
    ],
    "status": "ONE",
    "errorMessage": "ERROR with aKey"
  }
}
```

This is the function and the classes.

```
private fun ParseResponse(responseMessage: String): MyResponse{
    try {
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        return objectmapper.readValue(message, MyResponse::class.java)
    }catch (e: JsonProcessingException) {
      throw IllegalArgumentException("json was invalid $responseMessage", e)
    }
}

data class MyResponse(
    val meta: Metainfo,
    val datadetail: DataResponse
)

data class MetaInfo(
    val id: String,
    val time: Instant
)

data class DataResponse(
    val aKey: MyKey,
    val aTypes: List<TypesResponse>,

    val aNumber: String? = null,
    val status: StatusType,
    val errorMessage: MyErrorMessage = null
)

enum class StatusType{
    OK,
    ERROR
}

data class TypesResponse(
    val bKey: MyBKey,
    val cKey: MyCKey,
    val status: StatusType,
    val errMessage: MyErrorMessage? = null
)

data class MyErrorMessage(
    @JsonProperty("message")
    val message: String,

    @JsonProperty("context")
    val context: MyContext?,
){
    constructor(message: String) : this(
        message = message,
        context = null
    )

    enum class MyContext{
        ONE, TWO, THREE
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Kotlin, not Java, right? You probably need a Jackson Kotlin module if not already present

Comment: @GaëlJ Oh yes you're right. I fixed it in the post. The Jackson Kotlin module is already included.

Comment: That code does not even compile. `val context: MyContext?,` is conflicting with `enum class context{`. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON does not follow your class structure.
You have `"errorMessage": "ERROR with aKey"`, but your `errorMessage` in `DataResponse` is in fact a `MyErrorMessage` which is an object, not a simple String.

It would need to be:

```json
"errorMessage": {
  "message": "ERROR with aKey"
}
```

If that is not an option, then you need a custom Jackson JSON Deserializer for your `MyErrorMessage` that can handle that. You can check an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization#on-mapper).

Comment: Note that this _is_ the structure of the error inside the first element of `"aTypes"`, but it is _not_ the structure of the error inside `"datadetail"`.

Comment: @inconnu it seems that you unaccepted the answer. Any reason why? Do you still need help?

Comment: @JoãoDias Sorry, I clicked by mistake. Your answer was perfectly right :) Thanks again, I'm really grateful!